# Edit workspace files via jenkins UI

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there an easy way to edit our python files in the Jenkins workspace UI?

It would be super nice if we could get code highlighting too!

Comment: I don't believe there is, and it doesn't sound like a good idea. What's the use case (as opposed to keeping edits in your source repository)?

Comment: We use Jenkins for CI of our beta server, nothing in there goes to staging, let alone production. We would be editing files on the fly to do some testing, change config variables, etc. Our beta server is only used internally, and without sensitive credentials.

Comment: I've got to agree with @Christopher on this one. What you describe sounds like terrible workflow. You'd be better off having a beta branch on your repo and letting the job build from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can think of that Jenkins offers is a file upload. You can upload file with local changes and then trigger a build. This file will be replaced at already specified location. This feature can be used by making your build parameterized and adding `File Parameter` option. Below is what Jenkins says about the description of this feature.

> Accepts a file submission from a browser as a build parameter. The uploaded file will be placed at the specified location in the workspace, which your build can then access and use.
> This is useful for many situations, such as:
>
> Letting people run tests on the artifacts they built.
>
> Automating the upload/release/deployment process by allowing the user to place the file.
> Perform data processing by uploading a dataset.
> It is possible to not submit any file. If it's case and if no file is already present at the specified location in the workspace, then nothing happens. If there's already a file present in the workspace, then this file will be kept as-is.

Answer (score 2):

There is a jenkins plugin that allows you to edit files: [Config File Provider](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin)
It cant edit random file but you can use it to achieve what you want.

[image]

The storage of the plugin is in the form of xml files in jenkins folder. This means that you could create script that recreates those files wherever you need them by parsing those xml files (plugin does this for the workspace although it requires build setp). For instance, i could add new custom config file like this:

Name: script.sh
Comment: /var/log
Content: ....

This will be available then in xml file which you could parse within cron job to create actual files where you need them